# Multi page tiff program Blank pages

Tags: c#

I write a code to combine single tiff file to multipage tiff. but output come with the blank pages at the end. code works fine if the input files are black&White but not for colored .tiff files. for example if i give 100 files and as input output single tiff files come up with 47 pages and rest of them are blank.

i use standard code to achieve this functionality, following is my code. Anyone idea why ?

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameTemp, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapEncoder tifEnc = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapEncoder();
            tifEnc.Compression = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffCompressOption.Default;

            foreach (string fileName1 in filePaths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FileName:::" + fileName1);

                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmpImg = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bmpImg.BeginInit();
                bmpImg.CacheOption = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bmpImg.UriSource = new Uri(fileName1);
                bmpImg.EndInit();

                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.FormatConvertedBitmap fcb = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.FormatConvertedBitmap(bmpImg,
                                                  System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Rgb24,
                                                  System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapPalettes.Halftone27,
                                                  1.0);
                tifEnc.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(fcb));



            }

            tifEnc.Save(fs);
            fs.Dispose();


        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the sample below, BitmapImage is not loaded when you do bitmapImage.EndInit() as it seems to be doing lazy loading. If the memory stream is disposed, then the pages I get are also white because the image is not loaded. 
The second method takes a destination file path and a list of sources.

```
        public static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            return bitmapImage;              
        }

        public static void CreateTiff(string destPath, params string[] filePaths)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Append, 
                                                            FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var tifEnc = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
                tifEnc.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Default;

                foreach (string fileName in filePaths)
                {
                    var image = LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));

                    tifEnc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
                }

                tifEnc.Save(fs);
            }

        }
```